# NSBundle Not Working

Tags: xcode, path, directory, nsbundle

NSBundle outputs the old name of my app: "/var/mobile/Applications/0E1638D2-5B9C-4A1F-8ED2-5F8ADF55D3F6/distributedLCA.app"  but I renamed the project but it still prints out that old .app name.  Is there a way to fix this?

My code:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some lengthy google searching, I came across this bit of code that fixed my problem.  Instead of writing to the .app I write to the documents of the device:

```
NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docStorePath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [docStorePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/YOUR_FILE.txt"];``
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably hacen't changed the Product Name in your Build Settings.  In the Project Explorer View, click on your project.  Then Click the Build Settings tab at the top of the editor view.  Make sure your Product is selected in the left-hand editor view.  Scroll down until you see Product Name, and change the mame of your product.  Clean & rebuild.

Comment: I double checked, it is updated.  And I tried cleaning and building again (anyhow) and it still doesn't work right :(  Any other suggestions?